# Automation server can't create object

Tags: javascript, com, activex

I am writing a C# object that I need to be able to access from a javascript application.

```
var util = new ActiveXObject('Namespace.Class');
```

However, when I attempt to create the object I get an error saying, "Exception: Automation server can't create object." I have registered the object for COM interop and the assembly is signed.

NOTE: This is NOT a webpage and is NOT being run in the browser. I am able to create other COM objects in this same way, so my security settings are already set, and my script engine is working.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644828/activex-not-working-properly-with-default-security-settings

Comment: @Sheng Jiang: I am not working in the browser. I know that javascript is usually used in web development, but this is not a website or webservice.

Comment: What is your script host then?

Comment: msscriptcontrol. Found solution: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm just new to COM. Turns out I did not set com visible to true. Hope this helps someone!

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```