# Getting remote COM+ object fails from IIS, fails from .NET interop, works from WScript

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, com, windows-server-2003

I have Classic ASP vbs code that executes following:

```
CreateObject("MyCom.Type.1", serverName)
```

and it fails with

```
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'CreateObject'.
```

Also I tried calling following code from .NET interop lib thus:

```c#
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid, computerName, true))
```

and it resulted in

```
DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer x.x.x.x using any of the 
configured protocols
```

in the eventlog.

I also tried jscript in my classic ASP app that goes like:

```
GetObject("MyCom.Type.1", serverName)
```

And it resulted in "Automation server can't create object"

Although when i call vbs code from test.vbs using cscript.exe or wscript.exe, it works fine!
IIS pool works under my own identity, same I used for calling cscript. Also i .NET I noticed that the type returns fine, it fails on creating instance of one.

I suspect it has something to do with some esoteric settings of COM/DCOM. 
Please help, that vbs execution tells me this should be possible from under w3wp too

One more thing - server machine is Windows Server 2003.

Comment: This maybe helpful - [Event ID 10009 — COM Remote Service Availability](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774368(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Is the machine 64-bit? could it be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue?

Comment: maybe this helps? Server.createobject (as used in classic asp) and wscript.createobject (as used in cscript) are completely different things: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/01/145686.aspx

Comment: one more link (from above blog): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/14/58700.aspx

Comment: ulluoink, thank you, this is very helpful one.
The article states that context for transactions is created in ASP, and from comments I learned that problem is most likely in DTS - in my environment there are network security issues with distributed transations, we already encountered it in ADO SQL scenarios, seems like same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automation server can't create object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080734/automation-server-cant-create-object)

Comment: no, it's not duplicate
it's specific case where server name is specified, and server name is treated differently in IIS environment and in WScript